# Checking the number of digits from a string

Tags: java, android, regex

Does the following code ensure that the 'myteststring' contains only two digit numbers?If not, how to modify it?

```
if(myteststring.matches("^[0-9]*\\$")) 
{
// Do something
}
else {
// Do something else
}
```

Comment: @vks - that ensures only one , 2-digit number.

Comment: Why have you double escape the dollar?

Comment: `two digit numbers`, unclear..

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I think the OP wants `10` , `1234` to be matched but `1` , `123` to fail the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a string that contains at least one pair of digits, any combination of characters, and with the restriction that numbers are exactly two digits:

`myteststring.matches("^[^0-9]*([0-9]{2}[^0-9]+)*[0-9]{2}[^0-9]*$")`

To include the empty string:

`myteststring.matches("^[^0-9]*([0-9]{2}[^0-9]+)*([0-9]{2})?[^0-9]*$")`

To match a sting that contains exactly two digits:

`myteststring.matches("^[0-9]{2}$")`

Or

`myteststring.matches("^[0-9][0-9]$")`

The `^` means match the beginning of the line. When used inside of the square brackets, it matches the opposite of the pattern.

The `[0-9]` means match one of the. numbers from 0 through 9.

The `{2}` means match the previous regex twice.

The `$` means match the end of line.

Comment: This checks for only one 2-digit number :)

Comment: Ok, so you want to check for a string that can contain any character, but digits must appear in pairs of 2?

Comment: **contains only two digit numbers** - I think thats what the OP wants.

Comment: Ok, it can probably be simplified but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

use `(\\d{2})+` . This checks for pairs of digits.
[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/vJ0nX5/1)

Output :

```
myString ="123" --  > false
myString ="12" -- > true
myString ="1234" --> true
```